# Простая смена цифр от 28 до 0 за равный промежуток времени

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите, как реализовать это правильно

Comment: [setInterval][1] и вот [примерчик][2]


   [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
   [2]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/SCyWG/

Comment: Благодарю! минимум кода! У меня получилось намного больше кода наверное раза в три! Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: цепочкой setTimeout http://jsfiddle.net/SCyWG/2/

Comment: Благодарю еще раз!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю Deonis и eicto за помощь. http://jsfiddle.net/SCyWG/2/